# Data source for jQuery auto-complete plugin

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's auto-complete plugin for a simple search form. I am having trouble  converting my JSON object data into an array for usage with auto-complete.

My code:

```
var listOfOrderedByNames = getAutocompleteData();
$('#OrderedBy').autocomplete(listOfOrderedByNames);

function getAutocompleteData() {
    var output;
    $.getJSON('AJAX/GetOrderedByNames', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, optionData) {
            output += optionData + "|";
        });
    });
    return output;
}
```

My JSON data that is returned looks like this:

```
    ["Jimmy","John", "Etc",null]
```

For some reason it looks like what I'm getting back from that `getAutocompleteData` function is an empty string and I don't know what is wrong.

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. As soon as you send the request, your function `getAutocompleteData()` continues executing, returning nothing.

You should enclose everything in the callback function you're passing to the getJSON method:

```
var output;
$.getJSON('AJAX/GetOrderedByNames', function(data) {
    var output = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, optionData) {
        output += optionData + "|";
    });
    $('#OrderedBy').autocomplete(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `var ouput;` line to `var output = '';`